# Optimization and DFT-D3 energy calculation in GamessFireFly version 8.1.1

Tags: density-functional-theory

My input was

```
$CONTRL SCFTYP=RHF DFTTYP=B2PLYP DFTD=.T. d5=.T. RUNTYP=OPTIMIZE $END                 
$DFTD VERSN=3 $END                                                             
$SYSTEM TIMLIM=3000 MEMORY=30000000 $END                                       
$BASIS EXTFIL=.T.  GBASIS=acc-pvdz $END                                       
$STATPT HSSEND=.T. NPRT=-2 $END                                                
$FORCE NVIB=2 VIBSIZ=0.005 $END                                                
$DATA                                                                          
 H2O                                                                             
C1                                                                              
O  8.0                   -3.46278   2.54045   0.                                
H  1.0                  -2.50278   2.54045   0.                                 
H  1.0                  -3.78324   3.44539   0.                                 
 $END
```

I am getting the following error:
*`FATAL ERROR: DFTTYP = B2PLYP   DOES NOT YET HAVE GRADIENTS PROGRAMMED.`*

So is it not possible to perform optimization with this functional?

Answer (score 2):

In original GAMESS-US code there are no analytic gradients for "double hybrids" and it looks like it is true for Firefly as well. You can use numerical gradients by adding `NUMDER=.T.` in `$CONTRL` section. See [this](http://classic.chem.msu.su/gran/gamess/numgrad.html) for details.